# Issues with Custom Slide Application

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a custom slide calculator for our financial services landing page, much like the one on this page (www.advancedcommission.com). This is what I've written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset=”UTF-8”> 
<title> My Web Document</title>
 <script> function feeCalculate(slider){ if slider <=3000; 
var fee = 360; 
else; 
var fee = slider *.12; slideval.innerHTML = "$" + slider; } 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h2>Advance Amount</h2> Advance Amount: <input type="range" mine = "1000" max = "25000" value="0" step = "500" onchange ="feeCalculate(this.value)" style="width:400px;"> 
<span id="slideval">$1000</span> <h2>Fee: <span id="fee"></span><h2> </body> 
</html>
```

I pasted this code into Unbounce (our landing page application), but it's not working. Does the javascript have to be separate from the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It looks like slideval isn't set but it's hard to guess from just reading your code. Make a demo on codepen/jsfiddle/etc for us to have a look at.
2. If the number accuracy of your fee calculation matters then use something like big.js instead of normal floating point math.